# How to ask for audio autoplay permission on safari with javascript

Tags: audio, safari, html5-audio, autoplay

I have chat application. I want to narrate greeting message when user open the chat. When I try to play audio using `audio.play()` safari gives permission issue on console and doesn't play the audio.
[image]

However audio after first user gesture played well using javascript code. Currently, I show popup when fail to play audio so that user gesture happen.
[image]

Now I am looking for way to ask browser autoplay permission like we can ask for mic permission when chat is open by user first time so that custom popup will go away.
[image]

Here is my code

```
// initialise audio 
var ssmlAudio = new Audio();

// make browser ready to play audio

ssmlAudio.addEventListener('play', function () {
// When the audio is ready to play, immediately pause.
ssmlAudio.pause();
ssmlAudio.removeEventListener('play', arguments.callee, false);
}, false);
document.addEventListener('click', function () {
// Start playing audio when the user clicks anywhere on the page,
// to force Mobile Safari to load the audio
console.log("asdfasdrasdr")
document.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee, false);
ssmlAudio.play();
}, false);

// play ssmlAudio when greeing message appear
var promise = ssmlAudio.play();
ssmlAudio.src = 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3';

if (promise !== undefined) {

  // get user gesture for first time user
  promise.catch(error => {
    // Auto-play was prevented
    // Showing a UI element to let the user trigger click event

      // open popup so that user gesture happen    
      var permissionPopup = $('#autoplayPermission');
      permissionPopup.modal('show');

      // try to play audio message when user click on popup
      $("button.submit").click(function () {
        setTimeout(function(){ ssmlAudio.play(); }, 50);
        permissionPopup.modal('hide');
      });
    }
  });
```